# Vector fields on a sphere: equivalence of two definitions

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I'm trying to solve this differential geometry exercise:

> Show that a vector field on a $n$-sphere and a smooth map $\Phi: S^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $\Phi(x)$ is always orthogonal to $x$ are essentially the same object.

(The $n$-sphere is taken with its standard differentiable structure, given by the two stereographic charts $U,V$)

I think that this exercise requires us to find a bijection between the set of vector fields on $S^n$:
$$\text{Der}(C^\infty (S^n))$$
and the set of smooth maps that satisfy that orthogonality property.

I read a solution that went like this. On a stereographic chart, a vector field $X$ looks like this:

$$X|_U=\sum_i \varphi_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$

Evaluating this vector field on the function $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$, we get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x_1,...,x_n)x_i=0$$

So we just need to take $\Phi=(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n)$.

But this doesn't seem rigorous. The functions $\varphi_i$ are defined only on $U$ and not on the whole sphere, so we need to account in someway for the missing point.

Comment: Nice question. But topologist is only interested in continuous functions (maps). No differentiation. Right?

Comment: The solution is plain wrong. It is confusing chart coordinates with the standard ambient coordinates on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. But you can forget about charts once you know you have an embedded submanifold. You certainly can’t forget the embedding, since the result is entirely dependent on it.

Comment: Oh I see what you are talking about, but in this case the embedding is simply the inclusion in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. We are already considering $S^n$ as an embedded submanifold (precisely the radius $1$ sphere centered at the origin), so coordinates on  charts $(x_1,...,x_n)\in U$ are simply standard coordinates.

Comment: Do you know that vector fields can alternatively be defined as sections of the tangent bundle?

Comment: The first step is to show that $T_pS^n = p^{\perp}$, which means that it only remains to check that a vector field $X$ is smooth if and only if the corresponding map $\Phi$ is smooth, which you do using the fact that a chart into the sphere is a smooth map into $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$, since the inclusion from the sphere to $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$ is smooth.

Answer (score 2):

From $\Phi(x)$ we can construct a vector field in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ (where we indentify $T_x\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ ): $$X(x)=|x|\Phi\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right). $$ Now i use the following fact:
$X$ is a vector field in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $X(F)=0$ then $X_{|M}$ it's a vector field on M (where $M=F^{-1}(0)$ and $0$ is regular value).

In our case we have $F=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i^2-1$:
$$X(F)(x)=|x|\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\Phi_i\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(F)= $$
$$=|x|\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\Phi_i\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)2x_i =2|x|\left\langle \Phi\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right),x\right\rangle=0$$